# Allocating a 2D array in one function and reallocating it in another function?

Tags: c, memory-management

This is my code:

```
void allocating(char **word_array)
{
    int i = -1;

    while(i < 20)
    {
        i++;
        printf("%d \n", i);
        word_array[i] = malloc(strlen("hello good sir") + 1);
        strcpy(word_array[i], "hello good sir");
        if (i = 9)
        {
            word_array = realloc(word_array, 20 * sizeof(char *));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **word_array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);
    
    allocating(word_array);

    free(word_array);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", word_array[i]);
        free(word_array[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm playing around with dynamic memory allocation and I can't seem to get the code to work. It runs an infinite loop when i = 10 . Is there a problem with allocating the next memory location? Why does it keep printing 10 and not incrementing it?

Thank you!

Comment: `free(word_array);` and then you use `word_array` in the loop. How is that going to work?

Comment: Regardless, the allocating function doesn't work properly

Comment: Your main function is invoking undefined behaviour.  Anything can happen, including appearing to work.  Once you use `free(word_array)`, you can no longer legitimately access the array — in the following loop, those references are completely reprehensible.  If you put the `free(wordarray)` after the loop, you'd be in with a chance of it working correctly.  Use [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) if it is available on your machine.

Comment: Note that `if (i = 9)` is an assignment rather than a comparison (or as well as a comparison with zero).

Comment: Yep, one of many errors. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has multiple problems.  First:

```
if (i = 9)
```

This is an assignment, not a comparison, so because the value being assigned is non-zero the condition will always be true.  You want:

```
if (i == 9)
```

Second, you're looping one more iteration than you expect:

```
    while(i < 20)
    {
        i++;
```

When `i` is 19, the condition passes and the loop is entered, then `i` is immediately incremented to 20 which is past the bounds of the array that's been allocated.

Instead, initialize `i` to 0 and perform the increment at the *end* of the loop.

Third, when you do this inside of `allocating`

```
word_array = realloc(word_array, 20 * sizeof(char *));
```

You're modifying a local variable.  Changes to it won't be reflected outside of the function.  So when the function returns `word_array` in `main` will have the same value it had before, and if `realloc` moved the memory it will no longer be a valid pointer.

The function needs to be changed to take the address of a `char **`, i.e. a `char ***`:

```
void allocating(char ***word_array)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 20)
    {
        printf("%d \n", i);
        (*word_array)[i] = malloc(strlen("hello good sir") + 1);
        strcpy((*word_array)[i], "hello good sir");
        if (i == 9)
        {
            *word_array = realloc(*word_array, 20 * sizeof(char *));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

And the call changed to pass an address:

```
allocating(&word_array);
```

Finally, you `free(word_array)` right after the function returns and subsequenty use `word_array`.  Reading a pointer value after it has been freed is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Move the call to `free` *after* you've finished using the pointer.

Comment: This is an incredibly embarrassing post I apologise! Trying to rap my head around it but thank you very much!